Determine of value is optimal using sub-gradient method
Im currently trying to determine if my given value $x^*$ is an optimal value from the given information about subgradients at that point, and would like some help.
So the exercise is the following:
Consider the unconstrained optimization problem $$f^*=min \ f(x)$$
subject to $$x \in R^2$$
where $f$ is convex.
a) At the point $x=(2,1)^T$ we have that $f(x)=2$ and that $g=(1,-1)$ is a subgradient to $f$ at $x$.
What can you say about $f^*$ and $x^*$?
My solution:
Since we want to determine if $f^*$ is optimal, we use the optimality conditions that says that $f$ globally optimal $\Leftrightarrow$ $0^n \partial f(x^*)$ where $\partial f$ is the set of subgradients at a given point.
Since we have no more information about any other subgradients we can simply not say if $f(x) = 2 = f^*$. Is this a correct reasoning?
b) At the point $x=(0,1)^T$ we have that $f(x)=-1$ and multiple subgradients $g_i$ where $g_1=(-1,0), g_2 = (1,2)$ and $g_3 = (1,2)$ is subgradients to $f$ at $x$.
What can you say about $f^*$ and $x^*$?
My solution:
So again we want to determine if $0^n$ is a subgradient of $f$ at $x$. This can be achieved by combining subgradients with $3g_1+1g_2+2g_3=0$. However is this a valid reasoning? Or is there any other way of showing that the zero vector is one subgradient at $x$?
